# Django Want to count different item types

Tags: python, html, django, tags, count

Previously I had a client summary list in a table. In one column I had a list of object types and in another, I had the quantity of that object type.

```
@login_required
def client_summary(request, client_id):
    client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
    items = client.storageitem_set.all()
    tape_and_film_items = client.storageitem_set.filter(type="1")
    total_tape_and_film_items = tape_and_film_items.count()
    electrical_equipment_items = client.storageitem_set.filter(type="2")
    total_electrical_equipment_items = electrical_equipment_items.count()
    storage_office_equipment_items = client.storageitem_set.filter(type="3")
    total_storage_office_equipment_items = storage_office_equipment_items.count()


<table cellspacing="15" style="float: left">
<tr><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Quantity</th></tr>
</tr><td>Tape + Film</td><td align="center">{{total_tape_and_film_items}}</td></tr>
</tr><td>Electrical Equipment</td><td align="center">{{total_electrical_equipment_items}}</td></tr>
</tr><td>Storage Office Equipment</td><td align="center">{{total_storage_office_equipment_items}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now this would work, but there is a problem. I did not knew earlier that users could add their own storage object from a form in my web app. If they try add a new object type, it will not show up in my client summary unless I explicitly write up an django query in a view passing a variable in a template. If there was no form to add an object type, this would have worked.

So in my template now I have this now in the type column. This part will work because all I really need to do is list all the storage item objects regardless of whoever client it is.

**views.py**

```
item_type = models.StorageObject.objects.all()
```

**template**

```
 {% for item in item_type %}
     {{item.title}}
 {% endfor %}
```

But in the quantity column I can't seem to count. Returns nothing.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{item.type.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display some info of items for every tag, you can use [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag. If you want only quantity, use `Count` aggregation function.